# Issues with Firebase Analytics and iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am running a demo project on XCode Version 8.2.1 and developing with with Swift 3.0.

Normally, I do not use Cocoapods but decided to give it a try for the sake of learning.

I used the the steps listed in the [Official Firebase Get Started Tutorial for iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup)

I was pretty much successful in achieving what the aforementioned guide outlines.

My main intention to install Firebase was to use Analytics. As a starting project. I wanted to track which buttons are being pressed and then take it from there.

As you can imagine I am having great difficulty getting the button tap(events) to reflect in my Firebase console.

Heres the log from the console:

```
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.40100000 started
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To disable debug logging set the following application argument: -noFIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see some link)
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023009] Debug logging enabled
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS031010] Tracking view controller. Class, ID: SomeScreen, -863544045560073292
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS031006] View controller already tracked. Class, ID: SomeScreen, -863544045560073292
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS902004] Network status has changed. Code, status: 2, Connected
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS003007] Successfully created Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS029017] Configuration was not found in database. The configuration will be fetched from the network when necessary
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023016] Firebase Analytics is ready to receive events
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023080] Setting user property. Name, value: first_open_after_install (_fi), 1
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023087] User property set. Name, value: first_open_after_install (_fi), 1
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS032003] iAd framework is not linked. Search Ad Attribution Reporter is disabled.
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002002] Measurement timer scheduled to fire in approx. (s): 1562.119598150253
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023028] Upload task scheduled to be executed in approx. (s): 1562.119598150253
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS033003] Scheduling user engagement timer
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002002] Engagement timer scheduled to fire in approx. (s): 3600
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Firebase Analytics enabled
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023051] Logging event: origin, name, params: auto, screen_view (_vs), {
        firebase_screen_id (_si) = -863544045560073292;
        firebase_screen_class (_sc) = SomeScreen;
        firebase_event_origin (_o) = auto;
    }
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023073] Debug mode is enabled. Marking event as debug and real-time. Event name, parameters: screen_view (_vs), {
        firebase_screen_id (_si) = -863544045560073292;
        firebase_screen_class (_sc) = SomeScreen;
        firebase_event_origin (_o) = auto;
        firebase_realtime (_r) = 1;
        firebase_debug (_dbg) = 1;
    }
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023072] Event logged. Event name, event params: screen_view (_vs), {
        firebase_screen_id (_si) = -863544045560073292;
        firebase_screen_class (_sc) = SomeScreen;
        firebase_event_origin (_o) = auto;
        firebase_realtime (_r) = 1;
        firebase_debug (_dbg) = 1;
    }
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002003] Measurement timer canceled
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002002] Measurement timer scheduled to fire in approx. (s): 0.6096588373184204
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023028] Upload task scheduled to be executed in approx. (s): 0.6096588373184204
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002001] Measurement timer fired
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002003] Measurement timer canceled
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023033] Starting data upload
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023037] No data to upload
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023126] Fetching configuration from the server
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS900001] Downloading data. Host: https://app-measurement.com/config/app/1:827202604534:ios:74ac2b9799955a04?platform=ios&app_instance_id=C99433DC111F4ED98E7AEF83A87DC2B9&gmp_version=40100
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS901006] Received SSL challenge for host. Host: https://app-measurement.com/config/app/
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS901007] Cancelling authentication challenge for host. Host: https://app-measurement.com/config/app/
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS901017] Encounter network error. Code, error: -999, Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://app-measurement.com/config/app/1:827202604534:ios:74ac2b9799955a04?platform=ios&app_instance_id=C99433DC111F4ED98E7AEF83A87DC2B9&gmp_version=40100, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://app-measurement.com/config/app/1:827202604534:ios:74ac2b9799955a04?platform=ios&app_instance_id=C99433DC111F4ED98E7AEF83A87DC2B9&gmp_version=40100}
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023127] Fetched configuration. Status code: 0
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023128] Unable to get the configuration from server. Network request failed. Code, Error: 0, Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://app-measurement.com/config/app/1:827202604534:ios:74ac2b9799955a04?platform=ios&app_instance_id=C99433DC111F4ED98E7AEF83A87DC2B9&gmp_version=40100, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://app-measurement.com/config/app/1:827202604534:ios:74ac2b9799955a04?platform=ios&app_instance_id=C99433DC111F4ED98E7AEF83A87DC2B9&gmp_version=40100}
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023129] Network fetch failed. Will retry later. Code, error: 0, Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://app-measurement.com/config/app/1:827202604534:ios:74ac2b9799955a04?platform=ios&app_instance_id=C99433DC111F4ED98E7AEF83A87DC2B9&gmp_version=40100, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://app-measurement.com/config/app/1:827202604534:ios:74ac2b9799955a04?platform=ios&app_instance_id=C99433DC111F4ED98E7AEF83A87DC2B9&gmp_version=40100}
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002002] Measurement timer scheduled to fire in approx. (s): 1813.818364858627
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023028] Upload task scheduled to be executed in approx. (s): 1813.818364858627

On Loggin an Event from iOS Simulator

[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023051] Logging event: origin, name, params: app, select_content, {
        firebase_screen_id (_si) = 3219218616125876998;
        firebase_event_origin (_o) = app;
        item_name = Some Screen;
        firebase_screen_class (_sc) = SomeScreen;
        item_id = id-Some Screen;
        content_type = cont;
    }
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023073] Debug mode is enabled. Marking event as debug and real-time. Event name, parameters: select_content, {
        firebase_event_origin (_o) = app;
        firebase_realtime (_r) = 1;
        item_name = Some Screen;
        firebase_screen_class (_sc) = SomeScreen;
        firebase_debug (_dbg) = 1;
        firebase_screen_id (_si) = 3219218616125876998;
        item_id = id-Some Screen;
        content_type = cont;
    }
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023072] Event logged. Event name, event params: select_content, {
        firebase_event_origin (_o) = app;
        firebase_realtime (_r) = 1;
        item_name = Some Screen;
        firebase_screen_class (_sc) = SomeScreen;
        firebase_debug (_dbg) = 1;
        firebase_screen_id (_si) = 3219218616125876998;
        item_id = id-Some Screen;
        content_type = cont;
    }
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002003] Measurement timer canceled
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002002] Measurement timer scheduled to fire in approx. (s): 0.9640411138534546
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023028] Upload task scheduled to be executed in approx. (s): 0.9640411138534546
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002001] Measurement timer fired
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS002003] Measurement timer canceled
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023033] Starting data upload
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023037] No data to upload
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023126] Fetching configuration from the server
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS900001] Downloading data. Host: https://app-measurement.com/config/app/
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS901006] Received SSL challenge for host. Host: https://app-measurement.com/config/app
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS901007] Cancelling authentication challenge for host. Host: https://app-measurement.com/config/app
...............
and then it repeats itself..................
```

As you can see it says the following :

- **Firebase Analytics v.40100000 started**
- **Debug logging enabled**
- **Firebase Analytics is ready to receive events**
- **Firebase Analytics enabled**

All of these are very encouraging, but then these are followed by warning/error/info from Firebase such as :

- **Received SSL challenge for host**
- **Cancelling authentication challenge for host**
- **Encounter network error. Code, error: -999, Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"....**
- **Unable to get the configuration from server. Network request failed. Code, Error: 0, Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"**
- **Network fetch failed. Will retry later. Code, error: 0, Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"**

The pattern repeats itself when logging an event.

I never get a thing on my Firebase Console, even after enabling the Debug mode. Goes without saying, I read a lot on the issue online but to no avail.

Thank you for going through this long and possibly tedious question.

Any help/pointer would be appreciated!!

Comment: It looks like something is wrong with the network "NSURLErrorDomain" as it could be there has been a previous connection. Have you tried different devices? Does it happen on simulators?

Comment: @adbitx thanks for responding. Well I dint really try on any devices apart from the simulator. I work for a financial institution, so I suspect  one of the many firewalls implemented at workplace to be the root cause of this. 

Since this was a learning project I've shelved it all together. Will get back to it when required! :)

Comment: @iOSer were you able to fix this?

Comment: no bro since it was a learning project. I left it midway